# Problems with installation of OmniPascal

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnipascal

**I followed the instructions on http://www.omnipascal.com/:**

*Install Visual Studio Code and open it.  

Open View  Command Palette... and type ext install   

Search for OmniPascal and install it.   

Restart Visual Studio Code and open File -> Preferences -> User Settings   

Add the key objectpascal.delphiInstallationPath to the right editor

and set its value to the Delphi installation path.  
 
Don't forget to escape the backslashes!  

Perform a right click on the root folder of a Delphi project and select Open with Code*

**Extension Settings are:**   
`Omnipascal: Create Build Scripts` ->  `checked`   
`Omnipascal: Default Development Environment` -> `Delphi`   
`Omnipascal: Delphi Installation Path` -> `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\18.0`

Right click on the root folder of a Delphi project will open the project-files in vscode.  
`Run without debugging` will promt me to : 
`select environment` with the only option `node.js`.
Extension OmniPascal ist enabled, but does nothing. 
**What am I missing?**

Comment: As a matter of curiousity, do you have a particular reason for wanting to use OmniPascal rather than FreePascal+Lazarus?

Comment: @MartynA With FreePascal + Lazarus you cannot use Delphi code... (not 100% anyway) Since Delphi IDE chokes on every language feature introduced since 2010, VSCode + OmniPascal can serve as temporary IDE replacement.

Comment: @MartynA
Good question. My boss asked for this. He wants some external javascript-programmers, who use vscode, start with freepascal / delphi without changing their environment. He wants to spare them the need to make aquaintance of a new IDE, and by this achieving greater acceptance learning a new language.
I too really don't know what the benefits of coding in vscode are vs coding in Lazarus or Delphi.
But the boss asked for this.

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar
In vscode you switch between delphi and fpc compiler. Most code will compile not on both. It is possible to open code in both Lazarus and Delphi and check whether it compiles. I still do not see much benefit from using vscode.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar:  Actually, I've had no trouble converting a Delphi VCL db application (with minimal changes) to run on a Raspberry Pi   Although I've always been a Delphi fan, if I were starting a major project now, I would do it in FP on Lazarus, just from concerns about it being more future-proof.

Comment: @MartynA Like I said, it is not about converting... I don't have anything against FreePascal + Lazarus, but as long as Delphi is here it will suit my needs better. As for future proof, nothing is future proof...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar:  There are degrees of future-proof.  Imo, basing a project on an IDE that can't even be moved to a new machine without the IDE provider still being in business to activate it is an avoidable risk when there is an open-source alternative.  Ymmv.

Comment: @MartynA I have no problem there, still being on Delphi7

Comment: @penarthur66  Indeed.  I could certainly get by if I had to with D7, except for the lack of built-in Unicode support.  Not many of the later additions, like extended RTTI and especially generics, seem to me to be worth the trouble

Answer (score 0):

In `Extension Settings`

`Omnipascal: Msbuild Path` set to for eg `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild`
and check if this setting is found in the `CompileOmniPascalServerProject.bat` of your project `.vscode` folder.
Then open your project-file, right-click in the editor -> choose `Command Palette` and then Tasks: `run Test Task`  
This worked.

Comment: Just a note - this did not work for me at first. Then I found out that I needed to make sure I selected the 32-bit version of MSBuild instead of the 64-bit version. Then it worked.